# Angular.js in a ASP MVC 4 Envirionment Console Printes errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

I've a site with a small HTML , and angular code. The code works, and i'Ve the expected result. H2 shows the given string.

But the Visual Studio console prints out a error.

Can someonetell me one or if this is "as designed" ?

**Markup:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{Foo}}</h2>

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HelloWorldCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.Foo = "Dynamic Header";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error:**

> Exception was thrown at line 1124, column 11 in
>   `http: //localhost:31688/Scripts/angular.js 0x800a139e` - Laufzeitfehler
>   in JavaScript: No module: ngLocale

So  What does **No module: ngLocale** mean? and why to I get this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get Angular.js to work in a Windows 8 store app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792383/how-do-you-get-angular-js-to-work-in-a-windows-8-store-app)

Comment: I'm dealing with this error too and I'm not working with W8 store app at all. I'm running IE and this pops up.